# Questions relating to use of hacking tools described in a non-hacking scenario

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, question-quality

So there's a couple of questions over on the main site that have either been closed or have multiple close votes that essentially (to me) talk about using "offensive" security techniques (as opposed to defensive) in a scenario where the questioner describes their usage as legitimate.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/a-freinds-father-died-left-an-password-protected-ipad-is-there-a-way-to-unlock?lq=1

[Recover Server 2008 R2 Domain Admin Password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36780/recover-server-2008-r2-domain-admin-password)

the iPad one got closed at the domain admin password one has three close votes as it stands at the moment.

What I'd be interested to know is a bit more detail on why these are off-topic/bad questions?

Here's my take on it.  the iPad one is a scenario that is quite commonly faced and relates to security.  A relative dies and you need access to their computing equipment to close accounts/get contact details etc.

Isn't it a valid question to ask whether there is a legitimate way to bypass the security of the device to enable their relatives to achieve this task? The answer may well be "no there's no way of doing that I'm afraid" but that doesn't invalidate the question.

Same with the question on the person saying that they've forgotten their domain password and are looking to get access to the DC.  I'm not sure I see why that's not a legitimate query, it seems like a possible scenario (admins do forget passwords) and related to security.

Anyway pointers gratefully received :)

Comment: Re: deceased relative. This is a legal question; if a relative doesn't consider going to a lawyer, this is a sign of something going wrong. What's more, there's a risk of getting sued (not a lawyer myelf!) for somebody who answers under one's real name. The truth is there are legit ways to obtain access without turning to Sec.SE. As an aside, the iPad question was simply nauseating.

Comment: Sorry disagree you don't know that they've gone to the lawyer and are the executor of the estate.  One of the jobs as executor would is  contacting creditors and friends, and this information may well be held on an iPad. What legit ways are there of accessing an iPad without asking a question (on Sec.SE or elsewhere) and if that is the case should we not be pointing people in that direction instead of just closing the question?  Lastly no idea why you think that question is nauseating, people die and other people have to handle their estate, it happens.

Comment: You may have a point here. Agree on sending people to customer support.

Comment: Oh it's funny, such questions cluster up: [My kids are on my network](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36915/my-kids-are-on-my-network)

Comment: sure you and I know that there's no good technical block for kids on a network, but I think with questions like that we should take the opportunity to explain these things to people, what tech can and can't do for them :)